# create object-parent if undefined?

Tags: javascript

When making a javascript-variable you can do:

```
var hest = hest++ || 0;
```

I find this very useful. I'm looking for something similair when working with objects for example in this case:

```
self.counted[grouping][conversion]++;
```

if either grouping or conversion doesn't exist, I want it to be created. Is that possible? Also for pushing to an array that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: `self.counted[grouping][conversion] ? self.counted[grouping][conversion]++ : self.counted[grouping][conversion] = 1;` ?

Comment: why not handle that in your constructor?

Comment: @Maverick , constructor?

Comment: Will probably need more information on what this `self` and `counted` are in order for me to give you correct answer

Comment: @Mouser that won't work if grouping is undefined.

Comment: Basically, you will be using closure to return appropriate variation of the object and it's properties based on which one are available or defined

Comment: @KristofferNolgren true, but you can extend `self.counted[grouping] ? self.counted[grouping][conversion] ? self.counted[grouping][conversion]++ : self.counted[grouping]['conversion'] = 1 : self.counted['grouping'] = {'conversion' : 1};` In one line this will define all if absent, or update when present.

Comment: true that... but it lacks the clarity of the first example...

Comment: To my knowledge it is going to be difficult to achieve that clarity. You want to test two variables in one statement. But I can be wrong of course.